# Changing the photo in Google+ posts

Tags: google-plus

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to change the photo once it's been posted on Google+?

E.G. I posted some text and included an image below the post (in the add link, video, photo section). 
So, can I now edit that very post and just change the photo? When I try to do that, G+ gives me the option to edit the link only, not the photo.

Has anyone experienced issues like that, and is there a fix?

Answer (score 7):

That is not possible. You have to delete the post and make a new post.

Comment: Thanks @ade for the answer, though I knew that already. I was wondering if there is a way for changing the photo w/o deleting the post - sorry I didn't state that clearly in my question. :)

Comment: Sorry but there's currently no way to change the photo without deleting the post.

Comment: Thanks google, after sharing a link to the post I will invalidate it just to change a photo in that post, nice work, same in facebook.